# Passing Multiple Values

Tags: google-visualization, eventhandler

I have a visualization table that has an event listener on select.

**The need:** I want the user to be able to delete documents on the google drive without having to leave the webpage

**The set up:** I added a button so that when clicked, I get a confirm alert box that includes the value. Once I click OK, it runs the scripts from the client-side with an event handler. This works perfectly!

**The problem:** I can move one document at a time but if I need to move 20+ documents it gets really tedious to click rows one after the other. Is it possible to pass multiple values to the successhandler?

```
  google.visualization.events.addListener(archiveChart.getChart(), 'select', function () {        

        $("#docArchive").on("click", function() {

            var selection = archiveChart.getChart().getSelection();
            var dt = archiveChart.getDataTable();                
             if (selection.length > 0) {
              var item = selection[0];
              var docurl = dt.getValue(item.row, 2);
              var docname = dt.getValue(item.row, 1);
              var folder = dt.getValue(item.row, 4);

            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to archive " + docname + "?") == true) {
                  archiveChart.getChart().setSelection([]);
                 return google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessArchive).withFailureHandler(function(err) {
                     alert(err);
                   }).archiveDoc(docurl,folder);
                } else {
                  archiveChart.getChart().setSelection([]);
                }
           }}); 
      })
```

I feel like I might need to add this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
                var item = selection[i];
```

I'm struggling a little with understanding what I might need to change (still learning). Any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: the table chart does support multiple selections, it should be fine to add the for loop as you suggest...

Comment: So when I add the loop, still only one document name is in the alert box. If I click cancel, the alert box asks me for each selection, but if I click OK, it only carries out the script for one document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recommend confirming once, for all documents

then loop the selection to archive each document

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(archiveChart.getChart(), 'select', function () {
  $("#docArchive").on("click", function() {
    var selection = archiveChart.getChart().getSelection();
    var dt = archiveChart.getDataTable();
    var docNames = selection.map(function (item) {
      return dt.getValue(item.row, 1);
    }).join('\n');
    if (selection.length > 0) {
      if(confirm("Are you sure you want to archive the following document(s)?\n" + docNames) == true) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
          var item = selection[i];
          var docurl = dt.getValue(item.row, 2);
          var docname = dt.getValue(item.row, 1);
          var folder = dt.getValue(item.row, 4);

          return google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccessArchive).withFailureHandler(function(err) {
            alert(err);
          }).archiveDoc(docurl, folder);
        }
      }
      archiveChart.getChart().setSelection([]);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That did it! I can now see all of the selections in the alert box. I now just need to adjust the script that moves the files so that all files get moved instead of the first selection. Thank you so much!